# How to create Histogram?

Tags: java, histogram

I have to create a histogram that orders the heights of NBA players. The input goes in the console. This is what the output should look like:

```
Num bins: 16
Min: 63
Max: 91
Avg: 78.42798594847775
                                      722                         
                                      +-+                         
                                      |*|                         
                                      |*|                         
                                  611 |*|                         
                                  +-+ |*|                         
                              524 |*| |*|                         
                              +-+ |*| |*|                         
                              |*| |*| |*|     459                 
                              |*| |*| |*|     +-+                 
                          361 |*| |*| |*|     |*|                 
                          +-+ |*| |*| |*| 352 |*|                 
                          |*| |*| |*| |*| +-+ |*|                 
                          |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*|                 
                          |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*|                 
                          |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| 188             
                          |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| +-+             
                          |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*|             
                       88 |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*|             
                   53 +-+ |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*|             
    1   1   4   7 +-+ |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*| |*|  34   7   4 
------------------------------------------------------------------
 63  64  66  68  70  72  73  75  77  79  81  82  84  86  88  90
```

So far I have:

```
package a3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleHIstogram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Set up scanner for input from console.

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int bin = scan.nextInt();

    ArrayList<Integer> heights = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    int firstNum = scan.nextInt();

    double sumOfHeights = 0;

    int start = scan.nextInt();

    while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        heights.add(start);
        start = scan.nextInt();
        sumOfHeights += start;
    }


    int numOfPlayers = heights.size();
    double avgHeight = numOfPlayers / sumOfHeights;



    int minimum = 999999;
    for (int i = 0; i < heights.size(); i++) {
        if (minimum > heights.get(i)) {
            minimum = heights.get(i);
        }
    }

    int maximum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < heights.size(); i++) {
        if (maximum < heights.get(i)) {
            maximum = heights.get(i);
        }
    }

    // int[] heightArr = new int[maximum];

    ArrayList<Integer> heightArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = minimum; i < maximum; i++) {
        heightArr.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Num bins: " + firstNum);
    System.out.println("Avg: " + avgHeight);
    System.out.println("Num bins: " + bin);

    for (int i = 0; i < heights.size(); i++) {
        if (heightArr.get(i) > 0) {
            System.out.print(heightArr.get(i));
            for (int j = 0; j < heights.get(i); j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int j = heights.get(i) - 1; j < heights.get(i); j++) {
                System.out.println("*");
            }
        }
    }
```

The main problem I'm having is how to create the "bins". So far my output doesnt have any bins and isnt really formatted, and I want to know how I would do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Next step would be to establish the y-axis in units of an asterix - presumably a relative frequency.  Post that as an added detail.  Once you have that then it becomes a drawing program.

Comment: I'm not sure how you determine the baseline numbers.  Some are incremented by  1 and some are incremented by 2.  I thought baseline numbers were supposed to have the same increment.

Comment: Also your `avgHeight` calculation looks wrong - an average is the sum / count.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the "bins" is that you subtract the shortest player's height from the tallest person's height then you divide that by the number of your bins. So now you have one bin's size. With this number you know how to place a player in the correct bin.

For example you have 10 bins, the shortest player is 100 and the tallest is 200. So you know that (200-100)/10 is 10 so one bin's size is 10. The First bin is from 100 to 110, the second is from 111 to 120 and so on.

Next iterate through the players. The first player is 136. So (136-100)/10 is 3.6 which means that it should be in the third bin. So you add +1 to the third bin.

So The "bins" is just an int array with the number of the players.